# How to change label text in Pygubu / Python

Tags: python

Im trying to change label text property of Label in Pygubu GUI builder for Tkinter with code:

```
    fps_lable = self.builder.get_object('FPS_Label')
    txt = fps_lable.cget('text')
    print(txt)
    fps_lable.config(text='hello')
```

But nothing happens. I get the text from label and it prints out (txt var) but when trying to change the text to "hello"... no joy. 
Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fps_lable = self.builder.get_object('FPS_Label')
fps_lable.set('hello') # sets label to 'hello'
```

NOTE: FPS_Label must be the name of the 'textvariable' for the label in the gui.

Comment: In the current version it seems you need to use `get_variable` to get a string variable rather than `get_object`